# How do I go ahead in this?

Tags: sudoku

[image]
Got this from daily challenge of sudoku app.

Comment: Your sudoku image is a bit misleading because in the lower right quadrant, you don't have any 3's marked there for some reason.  So I'm not sure that your marks can be trusted at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not an easy one to tackle here to find a number. There are probably easier ways to chip away at the pencil marks (after filling in the missing $3$s as per JMP's comment), but...

> Labeling:
>  * the cells as $(column, row)$ with $(1,1)$ in the top-left; and
>  * sets as $\{\cdots\}$
>
>  *If $(7,1)$ were a $3$*
>  then $(7,8)$ is a $9$
>  and so $(6,8)$ would be a $7$
>  leaving $(6,1)$ as an $8$ and $(6,2)$ as a $3$
>  as such $(5,3)$ would be a $1$
>  so one of $\{(7,3), (8,3), (9,3)\}$ would be a $3$
>  but If $(7,1)$ were a $3$ none of $\{(7,3), (8,3), (9,3)\}$ could be a $3$
>  Therefore $(7,1)$ *cannot* be a $3$ and *must* be a $9$

Comment: Idk how you guys have so good eyes to spot such tricks. I try to use pencil markings and eventually I get lost, similar to what happened in this puzzle

Comment: This was a "guess and check" rather than spotting a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> r5c7 can't be a $3$, because then r1c7 and r3c7 are $6$ and $9$, which forces the remaining 2 cells in the column to be $5,7$, which forces a $6,8$ in the right column of the lower-right block, which means both r7c8 and r9c8 are $2$. Also the is only one option for the $3$ in r9.